# How can i get only integers from an list . Integers are in form of string

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a list. `l=['572399', 'a', '31727', 'rs', '824687', 'So', '505535']`
in which integrs are also in form of strings.
Like '31727'

I want to remove all the strings like... `'a' , 'rs' , 'So'` .. and convert '572399' to 572399
i want the list as= `[572399, 31727, 824687,505535]`

I tried

```
result=list(filter(int, l))
print(result)
```

But it gives error

Comment: Ofcourse it gives an error, everything in the list is a string?

Comment: yes thats the point..how can i covert the String 'Int' to genuine int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l=['572399', 'a', '31727', 'rs', '824687', 'So', '505535']
new_list = []
for i in l:
    try:
        new_list.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This works. It's a bit hacky, but it definitely works. I'm sure there is a more efficient solution out there, but this is one way of doing this.

```
>>> print(new_list)
[572399, 572399, 31727, 824687, 505535]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your beggining was quite good. The only difference is that we need to replace `list(filter(int, l))` with `list(filter(isnumber, l))` where `isnumber` returns `True` if its input is integer and `False` otherwise (unlike `int` which returns input translated to integer and this raises errors as in your case). Let's define `isnumber` in a following way:

```
def isnumber(text):
    return all([n in '-0123456789' for n in text])
```

Then an output of `result = list(filter(isnumber, l))` is:

```
['572399', '31727', '824687', '505535']
```

After that you are able to map all the items to integers by using

```
list(map(int, result))
```

or

```
[int(n) for n in result]
```

#### EDIT:

We can also replace

```
result = list(filter(isnumber, l))
```

With bultin equivalent of `isnumber` like this:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), l))
```

Comment: Yes its working..But considering efficiency and speed..which method should i go for?  By creating new function or as Riccardo Bucco said (builtins)?

Comment: First, try to avoid unneccessary iterations like doing a list in `list(filter(isdigit, l))`.

Comment: Ok, and now I am able to compare times for a list of 5000000 items:
`y = ['572399', 'a', '31727', 'rs', '824687'] * 1000000`. 
Time of `map(int, filter(lambda x: isnumber(x), y))` is 0.
Time of `list(map(int, filter(lambda x: isnumber(x), y)))` is 3.5.
Time of `list(map(int, filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), y)))` is 1.1

Comment: Finally `isdigit` is 3 times faster than my `isnumber` in case we use iterations wisely.

Comment: Will fail with `['+1']`

Comment: Oh, common... Add that '+' into my definition, if you really need to check such a strange integers

Comment: @MykolaZotko This solution would also fail with `["4+5"]` or `["-"]`

Comment: @MykoloZotko even `'+5'.isdigit()` fails. What are we going to do? Exceptions only?

Comment: I think using exceptions here is the best solution. [Asking for permission instead of forgiveness](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension. You just need to make sure that every character is a digit:

```
result = [el for el in lst if el.isdigit()]
```

where `lst` is your list of elements.

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, this solution does not work with signed integers such as `-1` or `+23`. If you want to keep also signed integers than you can slightly modify the solution in this way:

```
result = [el for el in lst if el.isdigit() or (el[1:].isdigit() and (el.startswith("+") or el.startswith("-")))]
```

Comment: It's possible to use `isnumber` function instead of `isdigit` method as I did in my answer

Comment: @mathfux why should I define a new function if I can use builtins?

Comment: In case you forgot it exists in builtins like I did :D

Comment: You approach will fail with negative integers: `['-1']`

Comment: @MykolaZotko I modified my solution. Now it's able to keep also signed integers. Do you like it now?